# Focus on next item in a ListView after deleting the selected item

Tags: c#, winforms

This may be simple. When I remove a ListView item I would like it to select the item that was above or below it. If I want to remove 5 items in a list, I would like to just click the remove button 5 times rather than having to keep selecting the item I want to remove. In this ListView I cannot allow multi-select.

```
    private void removeSelectionButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Remove Selection
        if (listView.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            listView.SelectedItems[0].Remove();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the index of the item you're removing, remove it, then set the selection to an item near the one removed.

```
var itemToRemove = listView.SelectedItems[0];
int selectedIndex = listView.Items.IndexOf(itemToRemove);
itemToRemove.Remove();
if (selectedIndex >= listView.Items.Count) selectedIndex--;
listView.Items[selectedIndex].Selected = true;
```

You may need to make sure the list view has focus (call `listView.Select()`) to see the selection or set `HideSelection` to `false`. Also you'll want to add a check around whether the last item was deleted before trying to set the next one as selected.

Comment: if there is only one item, this will cause `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.